# How to maintain correct parameter in htaccess rewrite

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm converting a few sites from one platform to another.  Both platforms use htaccess to rewrite the urls and to capture parameters from the url.

I have this rule currently on the new platform:

```
RewriteRule ^good-path/(.*).html$ /?kw=$1
```

and with that rule, a url like this, mydomain.com/good-path/nice-red-widget.html will pass the term "nice-red-widget" to the kw parameter, which is what I need.

My old platform had urls like mydomain.com/a-very-cool-nice-red-widget.hwp  (so all the urls on that platform had "a-very-cool-" in front of the parameter I'm capturing and had a .hwp for a url extension)

In an attempt to get my old urls to render and pass parameters correctly on my new platform, I added an additional rule so on the new platform, my htaccess looks like this

```
RewriteRule ^a-very-cool-(.*).hwp$ /good-path/$1.html
RewriteRule ^good-path/(.*).html$ /?kw=$1
```

With these rules, it appears that my pages are rendering properly, but the "kw" parameter is not being correctly captured.  On the new platform, mydomain.com/a-very-cool-nice-red-widget.hwp seems to render properly (renders the page as if it were mydomain.com/good-path/nice-red-widget.html), but instead of passing "nice-red-widget" through as the kw parameter, it passes "/a-very-cool-nice-red-widget.hwp" through as the kw parameter.

I'm driving myself crazy trying to figure it out.  Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: point all rules to the existent real path of the script. And escape special symbols like `\.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these 2 rules:

```
RewriteRule ^a-very-cool-([^.]+)\.hwp$ /?kw=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^good-path/([^.]+)\.html$ /?kw=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```